# Accessing User records in Sandbox: Error ID: 429448537

Tags: error, user, gack, spring19

This is mostly by way of information only.

Some of our user records in Sandbox have an issue that causes the error below:

It only affects the viewing of the user's page in the admin area, editing the record is possible.

> An internal server error has occurred An error has occurred while
>   processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been
>   notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional
>   information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the
>   error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of
>   the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well
>   as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using
>   salesforce.com!
>
> Error ID: 429448537-27451 (813506749)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an known issue at Salesforce and is currently being examined.

In my org it affects about 50% of my users.

My Case ID: #21283042

There are at least 3 cases with support on this issue.

Comment: Did you contact support? Could you include a case or issue number for other users to refer too if they encounter the same error & also need to contact support?